# Force-inject op into tezos-node?

Tags: node, p2p

Is it possible to inject an op into `tezos-node`, and tell it *not* to validate it before broadcasting it?

I'm running into an apparent bug in the logic of `tezos-node`.
Namely, if I try to inject an op but the gas limit is exceeded in the current candidate block, I get the error "The sum of gas consumed by all the operations in the block exceeds the hard gas limit per block".

While this error does make sense in the context of minting a block, it doesn't make much sense when you're just injecting an op into the p2p gossip network.
If there's no room in the current block, the op should successfully inject and then just sit in the p2p network until the next block.

Thanks!